# A continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$, such that no $L\gt 0$ satisfies $f(x) \ge L$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> (a) Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and suppose that $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$. Show that there is some $L\gt 0$ such that $f(x) \ge L$ for all $ x \in [a, b]$.

> (b) Give an example of a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$, such that no $L\gt 0$ satisfies $f(x) \ge L$ for all $x$.

I was given these two pribelsy together. For the first one I could solve it easily by using the property that $f$ will attain it's bounds in the given closed interval and hence the minimum value will do the trick.

But I can't prove (b) analytically.

I thought of $f(x) = e^x$ and I know it will work but I can't prove it using any contradiction.

Can I get some help please?

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$ is indeed  a valid example for (b).

Comment: @MartinR but I need to prove that there doesn't exist any such $L$ for this function and I'm stuck on the proof.

Comment: $e^x < L$ for $x < \ln(L)$ ... Or $\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function $f(x)=e^x$ is monotonically increasing on $\mathbb R$ you have that
$$
\mathop {\inf }\limits_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } f(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - \infty } e^x  = 0
$$
Thus you have that $0$ is the  g.l.b. It means that no $L>0$ can be a l.b for $f$. Therefore for each $L>0$ there exists a $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0)<L$.

Answer (score 0):

Let *f(x) = 1/(1+x²)* 
*0 < f(x) ≤ 1* for ∀*x*∈ℝ 
If L > 1 there is no *x* satisfies *f(x) ≥* L 
If 1 ≥ L > 0 all *x*∈ℝ can not satisfy *f(x) ≥* L.

Comment: Justify the 4th line.

Comment: @mr_e_man  consider the sign of f(x) - L since L>0 that is determined by the sign of   (1-L)/L - x²  and this is not negative only for particular x values but not for all real values of x .